# this.form.submit() not working while uploading directory

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
div>
  Select Folder to Upload: <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" onchange="this.form.submit();" class ="demoInputBox" multiple directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="" /><br/><br/> 
</div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="submit" class="submit" />
```

I am able to upload directory using the upload button, but when I write `onchange="this.form.submit();"` it doesn't work. 
Is it because I am trying to upload directory and hence onchange isn't working?

A solution would be extremely helpful. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:     `document.getElementById("myFormId").submit()`  Where myFormId is the id of the form

Comment: thanks, but this didn't work either. In my code, php script gets executed on submit. however when I am using either of the two solutions, it doesn't seem to work.